# How to prevent React Hook's useEffect from fetching data multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The example below shows how my use of `useEffect()` causes multiple Ajax requests. On the initial rendering of the component, this request is made twice. If the tag is changed, this request is made twice.

I can use some kind of internal state variables to track whether I have already fetched. Or I can create a kind of stack where I push on potential requests of a certain type, then before returning pop the stack and run the final request. But all of these seem like a hack.

(If it helps, the application is quite a bit larger, and I am using redux. Is a broader solution something like redux-saga's cancellation?)

```
const Thing => () => {
  const [tagId, setTagId] = useState(null)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    doSomeAjaxAndUpdateResults()
    setQuery('')
  }, [tagId])

  useEffect(() => {
    doSomeAjaxAndUpdateResults()
  }, [query])

  // ... bunch of extra effects with similar dependencies.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine both internal state variables into one `useEffect` hook and then if one change you can do `doSomeAjaxAndUpdateResults`

```
const Thing = (prop) => {
  const [tagId, setTagId] = useState(null)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    doSomeAjaxAndUpdateResults()
    setQuery('')
  }, [tagId, query])

  return ...;
}
```

Here's the live example that also relies on `props` being passed over: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wzmxmj

First render is with initial value, second render is with props being passed over and then subsequent props change will trigger one call each.

Comment: This works for the example I provided, but you did so by collapsing the logic into one useEffect method. I have many useEffect() -- I guess I should provide a larger code example!

Comment: My answer is within the context of your provided example, update it to your needs and will try again with different solution if it warrnts

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the same function in 2 useEffects, what you can do is to check first the useEffects you're watching at if it's `''` or `null` the `[tagId]` and `[query]`, you can try this code below. Hope it helps

```
const Thing => () => {
  const [tagId, setTagId] = useState(null)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if(tagId && tagId !== null) {
       doSomeAjaxAndUpdateResults()
       setQuery('')
    }
  }, [tagId])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(query && query !== '') {
      doSomeAjaxAndUpdateResults()
    }
  }, [query])
}
```

Comment: Javascript considers empty strings falser, so `query  !== ''` will only be false when `query` is also false. Also, in the case of checking against `null ` or `undefined`, `==` or `!=` will match both null and undefined, which is often what you want (but usually `===` or `!==` are preferred in other cases).

Comment: But in useEffect, it will initially run the useEffect `[query]` and `[tagId]` even if it's `''` or `null` so you have to check it first before doing actions when `[query]` and `[tagId]` values changed, that's why it keeps rerendering.

Comment: I think then your logic is backwards... maybe you wanted `if (!tagId && tagId !==null)…` and  `if(!query && query !== '')…` instead? This makes it so it only runs `tagID` related logic if the value is falsey but _not_ exactly `null`, and runs `query` related logs only if the `query` is falsey but not exactly `''`

Comment: Nope, `if(tagId)` means you're checking if it has value, lmao

Comment: You are checking if it has a _truthy_ value, `''`, `0`, `false`, `null`, and `undefined` are all considered "_falsey_" values by javascript. (sorry to belabor the point, but it is particularly relevant in your example). See https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ (third tab).

Comment: It's okay, I'm taking all your points and I'm learning but that's the way I do everytime I use useEffect. Thanks!

Comment: This solution works for simple case. I would find this hard to reason about if I had several variables to check.

Comment: Michael, It works fine, and it's a pretty decent habit. The one drawback is that it makes me wonder if you really meant to do something else, so it's unclear in that regard, because I overthink it. Javascript truthiness has bit me so many times....